# How to exclude empty line and number less than zero in python when using while loop

Tags: python, if-statement, input, while-loop

I am writing a simple program that executes if-else condition. my program receives from the user as input the weight of an object in kg.  , a floating number, and print out the price for shipment. by using while I want to Expand the program to function and calculate the total price for multiple packages. The program should load packet weight until the user enters a blank line or a number that is 0 or less. The program will then print the total price for all the packages

the code looks like this:

```
def packagePrice():
    weightInKg = float(input(" Enter the value of weight:"))
    totalPrise = 0

while weightInKg != "" or weight <= 0:
    if weightInKg <= 10:
        price = 149
    elif 10 < weightInKg <= 100:
        price = 500

    elif weightInKg  > 100:
        print ("Not allowed")

    totalPrise+= price
    print(totalPrise)

    weightInKg = float(input(" Enter the value of weight:"))

packagePrice()
```

but it does not properly run
anyone help

Comment: `it does not properly run` - what is wrong with it? Do you suspect any part of it? Have you tried printing stuff to see what might be happening? ... [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: _it does not properly run_ This isn't enough detail for us to help.  Tell us what actual problem you have.

Comment: up on compilation there is err with character input eg. ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'x' when I input the negative the, it simply accept but that is not what I want I want to exclude number less than zero as well as empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this answer the question ?

```py
def packagePrice():
    totalPrise = 0
    while True:
        weightInKg = input(" Enter the value of weight:")
        if weightInKg == '':
            break
        try:
            weightInKg = float(weightInKg)
        except ValueError:
            print("Text not allowed")
            continue
        if weightInKg <= 0:
            break
        if weightInKg <= 10:
            totalPrise += 149
        elif weightInKg <= 100:
            totalPrise += 500
        else:
            print("Not allowed")
    return totalPrise


print(packagePrice())
```

Comment: yes the out put exactly  works but not exactly the code I want. without try-except can we do. I don't understand much when yu used try-except.

Comment: _The program should load packet weight until the user enters a blank line or a number that is 0 or less._ --> You didn't say what the function was supposed to do if it received text, so I made sure it would start the loop all over again. ;)